# Stored Procedures vs Code in Database Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

What are the performance differences between accessing a database to query using ASP.NET Code behind against using SQL Stored Procedure

For ease of use, coding the query is easier, especially when coming to maintenance and changes.

However, a stored procedure is compiled in a database and run by the database.

Which one is more efficient, better to use?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? By _Codefile_ you mean via ADO.NET(which also enables to call stored-procs)?

Comment: I would imagine that `codefile` means an ASP.NET code-behind.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: There's no difference between codefile and codebehind in that case, but OP hasn't mentioned how he want to access the dbms(NHibernate,Entity Framework, LINQ-to-SQL,  ADO.NET, ...). This is even more confusing because you **can** call stored-procedures from "codebehind/codefile". So it's not clear at all what he wants to compare.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - My comment was general speculation on what might be meant, not a response to yours. `There's no difference between codefile and codebehind in this case` - that depends on what's meant by "codefile". `but OP hasn't mentioned how he want to access the dabase(NHibernate,Entity Framework, ADO.NET, ...)` - ...and? That doesn't really have anything to do with my comment. `This is even more confusing because you can call stored-procedures from "codebehind/codefile". So it's not clear at all what he wants to compare.` Agreed, it's pretty confusing.

Comment: ASP.net codebehind/codefile whatever they're called, i was tlking about a prepared statment using SQLCommand. Compare that from triggering a stored procedure. You OBVIOUSLY have to call the stored procedure from codefile but its when QUERING the database, which is better to use, but don't worry some already answered my quetion very well, so clarity in my question must have been sufficient!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server caches the execution plan of any query, SPROC or not. There is virtually no difference here. Basically, you save sending the query text over the network when using an sproc, nothing more. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx

Without and special reason being present, do what ever is more convenient to you.

The other answers suggesting generally better performance for sprocs are not true.

Comment: How comes you know the OP uses SQL Server? I don't know about SQL Server, but stored procedures are faster than queries for specific situations (I've tried).

Comment: I guessed because he was using asp.net. For SQL Server I can assure you this is the case. Why would sprocs be faster, anyway? The only reason can be plan caching which is the same for both cases (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055.aspx)

Comment: for example for very large queries or queries that compute stuff, so you avoid the latency.

Comment: The latency is only for sending the query text. Nothing more. You can send an entire batch just like you do with SSMS. Not one query but as many as you want in one string.

Comment: Only if the queries are all independent of each other. If I call a query that obtains data and based on that data start either Query 3 OR Query 4 (or whatever) I will have latency for every new query. Not so in Stored Procedures.

Comment: No. Your SQL batch can include all T-SQL constructs like if, while and exec. No limits at all. This is exactly the same way SSMS uses to send your scripts. SSMS does not parse your SQL. It just sends it all out.

Answer (score 2):

As long as it is a database centric query then the stored procedure will in most times be the faster choice (Performance).

But it is harder to maintain because its not in your regular source bundle.

"Better to use" depends on the requirements. If its okay when the query is a tad slower (like 1 ms VS 3 ms) then keep your code together and have it in ASP. If performance is the thing you want put it in the Database.

I put most of my queries in the code and only the ones that NEED the performance in the database.

Also it depends on the Database System used, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very incomplete as to what you are actually comparing.

Whether the SQL code is in a stored procedure or a full-blown inline SQL statement submitted from the client usually makes little difference (assuming proper parameterization and the SQL being non-pathological) to performance.  It can make a large difference in the security architecture and access required to be given to base tables or views instead of execution rights on procedures.  Stored procs encourage parameterization as a requirement, but parameterization is also possible with inline SQL.

If you are talking about performing logic against sets returned from the database versus doing the work in the database, this can go both ways - it depends upon the type of operation, the type of indexing, the bandwidth between client and database and number of requests needed to be serviced.

Usually, I'd look first at doing it in the database to keep the join/looping logic abstracted from the client and reduce data on the wire (both columns and rows) and present a simple data set API to the client, but IT DEPENDS.

Answer (score 0):

This is an "it depends" question.
Presuming this is SQL Server 2008R2 or higher Standard or Enterprise edition, stored procedures will cache differently than a TSQL statement.  Complex T-SQL statements will almost always perform worse than a stored procedure due to multiple things such as parameterization, code compilation, parameter sniffing, and various other optimizations.  In general, I prefer stored procedures as they are MUCH easier to optimize.  Plus you can change a stored proceudre without re-compiling and re-deploying any code.  And optimizations (such as "optimize for unknown" or 
"with recompile" can be applied to a stored procedure when parameter values vary drastically) can be applied to a stored procedure and un-done without end users even noticing (well, except for a performance change).

A stored procedure will always end up in the plan cache after a single run and will never be considered an ad-hoc query.  Ad-hoc queries, depending on SQL settings, may or may not be stored in the plan cache.  Plus adding or removing a character (presuming it is not parameterized) will cause SQL Server to build a new plan and building new plans is a slow operation.

TL;DR - preusming SQL Server 2008R2 or higher Standard/Enterprise; for simple queries, you will notice no difference.  For complex queries, stored procedure (if written properly) will almost always out perform T-SQL.  Stored procedures are easier to optimize at a later date as well.

Edit - added in SQL version.  I am uncertain about older SQL versions.